# How to select different sets of variables (ei value counts for a specific country) from a groupby df for a 2,2 subplot

Tags: python, pandas

From my original data frame, I used the `group-by` to create the new df as shown below, which has the natural disaster subtype counts for each country.

However, I'm unsure how to, for example, select 4 specific countries and set them as variables in a 2 by 2 plot.

The X-axis will be the disaster subtype name, with the Y being the value count, however, I can't quite figure out the right code to select this information.

This is how I grouped the countries -

```
g_grp= df_geo.groupby(['Country'])
c_val = pd.DataFrame(c_grp['Disaster Subtype'].value_counts())
c_val = c_val.rename(columns={'Disaster Subtype': 'Disaster Subtype', 'Disaster Subtype': 'Num of Disaster'})
c_val.head(40)
```

**Output:**

```
Country         Disaster Subtype        
Afghanistan     Riverine flood              45
                Ground movement             33
                Flash flood                 32
                Avalanche                   19
                Drought                      8
                Bacterial disease            7
                Convective storm             6
                Landslide                    6
                Cold wave                    5
                Viral disease                5
                Mudslide                     3
                Severe winter conditions     2
                Forest fire                  1
                Locust                       1
                Parasitic disease            1
Albania         Ground movement             16
                Riverine flood               8
                Severe winter conditions     3
                Convective storm             2
                Flash flood                  2
                Heat wave                    2
                Avalanche                    1
                Coastal flood                1
                Drought                      1
                Forest fire                  1
                Viral disease                1
Algeria         Ground movement             21
                Riverine flood              20
                Flash flood                  8
                Bacterial disease            2
                Cold wave                    2
                Forest fire                  2
                Coastal flood                1
                Drought                      1
                Heat wave                    1
                Landslide                    1
                Locust                       1
American Samoa  Tropical cyclone             4
                Flash flood                  1
                Tsunami                      1
```

However, let's say I want to select these for and plot 4 plots, 1 for each country, showing the number of each type of disaster happening in each country, I know I would need something along the lines of what's below, but I'm unsure how to set the x and y variables for each -- or if there is a more efficient way to set the variables/plot, that would be great. Usually, I would just use loc or iloc, but I need to be more specific with selecting.

```
fig, ax = subplots(2,2, figsize(16,10)

X1 = c_val.loc['Country'] == 'Afghanistan' #This doesn't work, just need something similar
y1 = c_val.loc['Num of Disasters']

X2 = 
y2 = 

X3 = 
y3 =

X4 = 
y4 = 

ax[0,0].bar(X1,y1,width=.4, color=['#A2BDF2'])
ax[0,1].bar(X2,y2,width=.4,color=['#A2BDF2'])
ax[1,0].bar(X3,y3,width=.4,color=['#A2BDF2'])
ax[1,1].bar(X4,y4,width=.4,color=['#A2BDF2'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, an simple way is to use [`catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) from [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) package:

```
# Python env: pip install seaborn
# Anaconda env: conda install seaborn

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = sns.catplot(x='Disaster Subtype', y='Num of Disaster', col='Country', 
                data=df, col_wrap=2, kind='bar')

g.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)
g.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Catplot]

**Update**

> How I can select the specific countries to be plotted in each subplot?

```
subdf = df.loc[df['Country'].isin(['Albania', 'Algeria'])]

g = sns.catplot(x='Disaster Subtype', y='Num of Disaster', col='Country', 
                data=subdf, col_wrap=2, kind='bar')
...
```

Comment: That is getting close, however, I have a follow up question: Since I have more than 4 countries in the df, how can I be more specific and using col='Country', which will graph all in the column, to be more specific and select specific countries in that column.

Comment: You want multiple countries on the same plot? Like `Countries = ['Country1', 'Country2', ...]`

Comment: No sorry, I want it like you have it, but how I can select the specific countries to be plotted in each subplot. Instead of just referencing the column with all the countries. As the full df as 70 countries in it, not only 4. -- yes something like the [country1, country2, ..] - I thought I'd create a variable list with the specific countries, using a filter, but that didn't work

Comment: What is the type of `c_val`: Series or DataFrame?

Comment: I converted it to DF

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please?